# React And Django Deployment on heroku

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, npm-scripts

I am badly stuck in deployement, I am trying to deploy the react django together on heroku,the problem is react app is not loading when i hit url it shows blank page and I can't get what the problem is it might be of build directory,where I think the path is not correct when made initial build "npm run build".Here's my below try:

[image: All the files are in root]

**Settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('automation/', include('performaApp.urls')),
    re_path('.*',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
    #url(r'^', FrontendAppView.as_view())
]
```

**build/index.html**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><title>Cameria - Facial Recognition</title><link href="/static/css/main.1ec2ccf3.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.40de23a7.js"></script></body></html>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-starter-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://adidas008.herokuapp.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.0.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-webcam": "^0.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.18.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  }
}
```

I think the main issue is the path of css or manifest files, thats why it may not loading react app,when I go to url it shows blank page and when I open console it giving me below errors :

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://adidas008.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.1ec2ccf3.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
register:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://adidas008.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.40de23a7.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
static/manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
register:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://adidas008.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.1ec2ccf3.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled
```

**Blank screen**:

[image]

Kindly someone suggest I am stuck in this for so long,In my opinion it may be build directory fault,is the paths in index.html is valid,it was automatically made when I ran "npm run build".How can I load my react app.What can I fix?

Comment: Did you moved the build file alone to the server ?

Comment: in index.html file, Just Add <base href="/"> in head before linking all CSS files . It may work when you mention the error Refused to apply style .

Comment: @Raghul alone means? I have moved with complete files

Comment: @Raghul I have tried <base href="/">

Comment: @Raghul another thing I want to confirm when I deploy to heroku do I need to add node modules and build folder?

Comment: no you just add the build folder alone

Comment: when you add the build folder you need to set the homepage as /yourpath/build

Comment: means in my case the homepage will be https://adidas008.herokuapp.com/build? in package.json

Comment: I have added homepage in package.json

Comment: yes before we build we have to add. once build is done need to move the build folder or files inside the build to the server

Comment: Still can't get it right can you tell in shorter steps of whole process in react part deploying

Comment: Try this first :  Set homepage in the package.json then take the build of the project, then move the files inside the build folder to server.

Comment: @Raghul still unable to resolve it, I have also uploaded the error screen (Blank screen) in question.

Comment: currently having this issue, Were you able to solve it? @NabeelAyub

Comment: Nope I am still on it, its the issue path you are using in index file in build, everything is correct but somehow the build is not being correctly made, check the paths related in index,manifest present in build directory

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA if you able to fix then kindly share with me also.

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA, also check while making Debug=True.

Comment: my error came from the wsig file. Can you share a screenshot @NabeelAyub

Comment: Were you guys able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this from your configuration:

```
class Assets(View):

def get(self, _request, filename):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static", filename)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type="application/javascript")
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

Without this, Heroku will be receiving all statics with the default `content-type` for Django http requests, which is `text/html`. They need to be `application/javascript` in this case.

The whole thing with some gotchas is quite detailed here:
https://dev.to/mdrhmn/deploying-react-django-app-using-heroku-2gfa